# undefined, null is not an object error with react native get location

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, react-native

I'm trying to make a simple map based app with react native and the only problem I've encountered is with the react-native-get-location library. Whenever I try to call it, it just results in:

> undefined, null is not an object (evaluating 'ReactNativeGetLocation.getCurrentPosition')

I've seen a couple of posts about the same error, but the devs just attribute it to faulty installation and close the post. I've uninstalled and reinstalled the package several times, used the base code provided in the examples, and am still getting the same error. I have no idea what could be causing this.

The problematic snippet:

```
state = {
  location: null,
  loading: false,
}

_requestLocation = () => {
  this.setState({ loading: true, location: null });

  GetLocation.getCurrentPosition({
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 150000,
  })
      .then(location => {
          this.setState({
              location,
              loading: false,
          });
      })
      .catch(ex => {
          const { code, message } = ex;
          console.warn(code, message);
          if (code === 'CANCELLED') {
              Alert.alert('Location cancelled by user or by another request');
          }
          if (code === 'UNAVAILABLE') {
              Alert.alert('Location service is disabled or unavailable');
          }
          if (code === 'TIMEOUT') {
              Alert.alert('Location request timed out');
          }
          if (code === 'UNAUTHORIZED') {
              Alert.alert('Authorization denied');
          }
          this.setState({
              location: null,
              loading: false,
          });
      });
}


const DirectionScreen = ({ navigation}) => {
  console.log("Trying to get Loc");
  console.log(_requestLocation());
  if(loading) {return(<View></View>);}
  return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView
        style={styles.map}
        customMapStyle={mapstyle}
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE} 
        initialRegion={{
        latitude: -22.987499636112343, 
        longitude: -43.228640763675564,
        latitudeDelta: 0.1822,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0821,
      }}>
        <MMarkers list={existing_places}/>
        <MapViewDirections
          origin={existing_places[0].coordinate}
          destination={existing_places[1].coordinate}
          apikey={GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}
          strokeWidth={2}
          strokeColor="hotpink"/>
      </MapView>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.menu_button} onPress={()=>navigation.toggleDrawer()}>
        <Image source={require('./img/menu.png')} style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }}/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Image source={require('./img/logo.png')} style={{ width: 40, height: 40, alignSelf:'center',top:"-90%",}}/>
    </View>  
  );
};
```

I've also tried using

```
GetLocation.getCurrentPosition({
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    timeout: 15000,
})
.then(location => {
    console.log(location);
})
.catch(error => {
    const { code, message } = error;
    console.warn(code, message);
})
```

But that also does not work

Comment: Can you use https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service ?

Comment: The library states that there are requirements to use the library, have you checked those? You also need to check location permission for Android and iOS as mentioned in the doc: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-get-location